# Android FAB not respecting WindowInsets in edge-to-edge xml layout with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, android-architecture-components, windowinsets

My goal is to have an app layout that has a fairly constant navigation UI with various content screens.

So my idea was to use the *android architecture navigation component* and host an `FragmentContainerView` for the varying screens (fragments) in the one and only `MainActivity`, which provides the navigation UI (`DrawerLayout`etc.).

My problem right now is getting edge-to-edge right: The fab in the fragment sits behind the navigation bar, so I guess the property `fitsSystemWindows=true` from the parent isn't propagated down to the fragment?

[image]

Having searched and read corresponding articles from [ian](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) and [banes](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1) I tried to manually set the fab margins in the `Fragment` which did the trick. But know, if a `Snackbar` appears the fab gets kicked upwards (good) but it keeps the margin from the inset, so is way to high over the snackbar.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val mab = binding.fab.marginBottom
        val mat = binding.fab.marginRight
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.fab) { v, windowInsets ->
            val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                bottomMargin = insets.bottom +mab
                rightMargin = insets.right + mat
            }
            windowInsets
        }
```

[image]
[image]

So my questions is if for the layout I described the following xml is appropriate and if so, how can I make the fab respect the `windowInsets` while keeping the default space to the snackbar? Note - there is a smiliar issue but not really solved (the marked solution has the same flaw as the author noticed later) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57293449/20926873).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_menu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The first fragment would be structured like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```